# Google map marker positioned in bottom on load

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am using bootstrap for layout and i am trying to center my map to a marker, but the problem is that the marker shows up at the bottom of the map container. If i slightly resize the window then it centers itself and work normally.

### my mark up

```
<div id="gMap">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div><!--gMap-->
```

### css

```
#map-canvas {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 70%; 

}

#map-canvas iframe {
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}
```

### js

```
var respMap;
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

function mymapini() {
 var mapPos = new google.maps.LatLng(43.724243, -79.634353); //Set the coordinates
 var mapOpts = {
 zoom: 16, 
 disableDefaultUI: true,
 center: mapPos, 
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

respMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,
mapOpts);

var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: mapPos,
 map: respMap,
 title: 'Test marker'
 });


 google.maps.event.addListener(respMap, 'idle', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
 respMap.panTo(mapMarker.getPosition());
 }, 250);    
});

}

if(mapCanvas != null){

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mymapini);


}
```

Comment: If you use percentage sizing, the parent div (gMap) needs to have a size.

Comment: i tried gMap width 100% and height 600px but result is same :(

Comment: That doesn't define a size for gMap (unless it's parents are completely defined/have a fixed size), you need to go all the way up to "html". See [this page from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Comment: thank you for the reply, 
fixed this by this css

#map-canvas {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 70%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
}

#map-canvas iframe {

    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the idle event, why not use:

```
respMap.panTo(mapMarker.getPosition());
```

inside an onload?

```
window.onload = function() {
    respMap.panTo(mapMarker.getPosition());
}
```

Or just do this:

```
var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: mapPos,
 map: respMap,
 title: 'Test marker'
});

respMap.panTo(mapMarker.getPosition());
```

Comment: tried it, still the same result.